# Some weird date while using datetimepicker on Python + Django

Tags: python

'''python
THE PROBLEM
I'm trying to create a datetimepicker field. Getting a weird date such as the one in picture 1. Notice that the date in the calendar shows year 2093 rather than 2019. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
[image: Picture 1]

I've been trying many things with calendar such as formatting, removing formats, adding and removing format in settings.py through DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS, and so on and so forth.

SOME CODE

```py
#-->>> settings.py - now commented
#DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',       # '10/25/06 14:30:59'

#-->>> models.py
class TB_production_order_step1(models.Model):
...
pjs1_start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
...
#-->>> forms.py
class PO_step1_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TB_production_order_step1
        fields = ('pjs1_prod_order',
                  'pjs1_material_code' ,
                  'pjs1_start_date',
                  )

#-->>> PO_step1_Form.html
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#id_pjs1_start_date').datetimepicker();
        });
     </script>
```

'''

Comment: You may have to tell datetimepicker what format to expect when initialising it.

Comment: Sorry for the dummy question, but how?

Answer (score 0):

IT WAS
class TB_production_order_step1(models.Model):
    ...
    pjs1_start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
IT IS NOW
class TB_production_order_step1(models.Model):
    ...
    pjs1_start_date = models.DateTimeField()

** Solution: removed the default=now from the models.Model field.